# Export KNN best estimator from GridSearchCV to PMML

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, grid-search, pmml

I tried to save **KNN** model to **PMML** in anaconda. But it doesn't work.

My script:

```
#### load iris dataset
iris_dt = pd.read_csv('iris.csv' , header = 0)
#### Create development and evaluation samples
X_train_dev, X_test, y_train_dev, y_test =  train_test_split(iris_dt.ix[:, 0:4],
                                                         iris_dt['Species'],
                                                test_size=0.05,
                                                random_state=36851235,
                                                stratify=iris_dt['Species'])
#### Train KNNClassifier
# tune CV
crossv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=36851234)
# tune GridSearchCV parameters
param_grid = {'n_neighbors': np.arange(1, 30)}

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn_randomcv = RandomizedSearchCV(knn,
                              param_grid ,
                              n_iter = 15,
                              scoring = 'f1_weighted',
                              cv = crossv,
                              random_state=36851232)
knn_randomcv = knn_randomcv.fit(X_train_dev, y_train_dev)  

# choose best estimator
knn_best_random = knn_randomcv.best_estimator_

#### Save best estimator like pmml
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([("knn_best_estimator",knn_randomcv.best_estimator_)])

pipeline.active_fields = X_train_dev.columns.values
pipeline.target_field = y_train_dev.name

sklearn2pmml(pipeline, "KNNFit_py.pmml", debug = 'True')
```

My debug log:

- python: 2.7.14
- sklearn: 0.19.1
- sklearn.externals.joblib: 0.11
- pandas: 0.20.3
- sklearn_pandas: 1.6.0
- sklearn2pmml: 0.35.0

When I tried launch java converter I get more detailed error:

```
SEVERE: Failed to convert
java.lang.ClassCastException: numpy.core.Scalar cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.getNumberOfNeighbors(KNeighborsClassifier.java:70)
    at sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsUtil.encodeNeighbors(KNeighborsUtil.java:130)
    at sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.encodeModel(KNeighborsClassifier.java:57)
    at sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.encodeModel(KNeighborsClassifier.java:32)
    at sklearn2pmml.pipeline.PMMLPipeline.encodePMML(PMMLPipeline.java:161)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.run(Main.java:145)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.main(Main.java:94)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: numpy.core.Scalar cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.getNumberOfNeighbors(KNeighborsClassifier.java:70)
    at sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsUtil.encodeNeighbors(KNeighborsUtil.java:130)
    at sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.encodeModel(KNeighborsClassifier.java:57)
    at sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.encodeModel(KNeighborsClassifier.java:32)
    at sklearn2pmml.pipeline.PMMLPipeline.encodePMML(PMMLPipeline.java:161)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.run(Main.java:145)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.main(Main.java:94)
```

Any help, please.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation:

```
n_neighbors : int, optional (default = 5)

    Number of neighbors to use by default for kneighbors queries.
```

`n_neighbors` should be a simple `int`.

When you do `np.arange(1, 30)`, it returns a `numpy.int64`, not python inbuilt `int`. Sklearn-jpmml cant handle numpy.int64 in place of int I think and hence the error:

```
numpy.core.Scalar cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

Change to:

```
param_grid = {'n_neighbors': range(1, 30)}
```

and the error will be gone.

Edit: Have posted a github [issue on the problem here](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn/issues/74).

Comment: This issue has been fixed here: 
https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn/commit/9192e0ca4e083442502ab103ea6a41c11a7de86f. More details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jpmml/WZIpILIyaao

Comment: @Claire Yes I saw that. I posted the issue on github with the same workaround there. :)